# How can we search for specific keyword on the web page content?

Tags: web-scraping, text-mining, text-analysis

I was wondering whether there are the library to identify the content part of web page. Example: I have a web page about the article of the news which has included the menu style on the header , the advertisement on the right side bar, the related link on the footer, and the content of that article in the middle of page. I want the system to be able to identify where is the most important content and then we are going to look for some matched keyword on that part, rather than search overall on the page.

Comment: (heuristic) headers, sidebars, and footers are easy to identify. They are generally redondant in a web site from one page to another. Everything else can be an important content

Comment: but i wonder how can we identify that it is the header or footer?

Comment: use a diff library to compare your pages.

Comment: could you share me what is that library ?

Comment: [A tool](http://www.altova.com/images/screenshots/xml-compare-diffdog.png) that can tell you the differences between two strings